# many ID's one form

Tags: php

I am trying to display two sets of data from a table. I'm making a shop for my game, and have a database that lists the pokemon/price/type/id of the pokemon in the shop. Right now I have it almost working, it displays all the pokemon in the shop and they all have a buy button underneath them, but for some reason no matter what pokemon you try to buy it only buys the one on the top of the list. I hope I explained it well enough here is my code.

```
if ($_POST['A'] == '1' ) {
$token= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);
$tokenn = strip_tags($token);


$sql234 = "SELECT * FROM ticketshop";
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticketshop");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){


$sql23 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."')";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "You have ".$row['ticket']." Tickets" ;
    echo "<p></p>" ;
if (isset($_POST['slot1'])) {
    if ($row['ticket'] >= $row2['price']) {
        echo "You have bought ".$row2['pokemon']."" ;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ticket=ticket-".$row2['price']." WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_pokemon 
(pokemon, belongsto, exp, time_stamp, slot, level, type) VALUES ('".$row2['pokemon']."','".$_SESSION['username']."', 100,'".time()."','0', '5', '".$row2['type']."' )") 
            or die(mysql_error());  
    } else {
        echo "You can't afford ".$row2['pokemon']."";
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in your PHP server logs? And what do you mean by the first set of code works?

Comment: What is the server error?

Comment: You might want to remove the `mysql_close()` call from before you list the pending applications.

Comment: @andrewsi how would i check my PHP logs? I mean that before a i added the second query (sql2, rs2) and everything under "Listing of completed applications".

Comment: @PatrickEvans It is the general "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: I see something strange in `mysql_select_db(twa312, $conn)` is twa312 a constant defined somewhere? If not, you should either use $twa312 or 'twa312'

Comment: @Muc It is the name of the database i am connecting too

Comment: @francis so use mysqli_select_db($conn, 'twa312')

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are closing connection to database and after you try to fetch result from second query which ends up with the error

```
<?php } /* mysql_close($conn);*/ /*comment or remove closing connection*/ ?>

<p><b>Listing of pending applications</b></p>
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I tried removing the <?php } mysql_close($conn); ?> but still getting the same error and thank you i will change the to mysqli